Conservation of Momentum in particle splitting. Is it always conserved?
Let an intially stationary particle $A$ of mass $m$, if $A$ explodes such that it breaks into 2 equal pieces.(Assume no heat or sound energy loss)
The red point is supposed be the point at which the explosion originates. Then here, mathematically the explosion energy changes to K.E of B and C, but intuitively, it feels like.. energy of explosion pushes the particles.. which causes change of explosion energy into Kinetic energy. The Question- Is Momentum conserved in this case? Though in this case it definitly feels like it does but to show/proove it is conserved i need to show that there is no external force in the system. This is where i'm getting confused coz the way i understand internal force is, Particle 1 applies force on Particle 2 and Par.2 applies reactionary force on P1 (this ensures that momentum lost by one particle is gained by other). But here it feels like the explosion Energy applies force on Part.1 (B) and same explosion Energy applies force on Part.2 (C), the idea of reactionary force is somehow dissolved, thus momentum lost by 1 particle may not be gained by another particle. And thus i began to form a conclusion that momentum may not always be conserved in such cases.
This part below is answered
A case which further advances my doubt is, what if we devise such a mechanism that explosion originates at left most point of $A$( the red spot)
then the final momentum has to be towards right, so momentum again not conserved.

I think this idea of energy applying force is main thing that guides me to this conclusion.
So, how am i wrong here?

In your second case, if the round mass moves to the right then it must be that some of the components of the explosive move to the left at high velocity in order to conserve momentum.

So momentum is definetly conserved in every case, which should be true, but can i prove(or understand intuivitively) for every case that the forces applied by this explosion energy on particles B and C is always like internal forces so momentum is bound to conserve, that is, it cannot act indiscriminately among particles giving one more momentum than the other.

If a component of the explosive applies a force on B (or C), then B (or C) applies an equal and opposite force on it. Those are all internal forces.
